# PowerMock EasyMock Fundamentals

Tags: java, junit, easymock, powermock

This one is probably a PowerMock/EasyMock 101 question which I cannot figure out why.
I have a class C with methods

```
public static boolean testInner(String s) {
    return false;
}

public static boolean testOuter() {
    String x = "someValue";
    return testInner(x);
}
```

In my test of testOuter() method I want to ensure testInner is called with appropriate parameter. To do so, I am doing something like this: [@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(EmailUtil.class) declared at Class level]

```
EasyMock.expect(C.testInner("blabla")).andReturn(true);
PowerMock.replayAll();
boolean status = C.testOuter();
PowerMock.verifyAll();  
assertTrue(status);
```

But I am getting error as:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Unexpected method call testOuter():
testInner("blabla"): expected: 1, actual: 0
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:45)
    at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.invoke(EasyMockMethodInvocationControl.java:95)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:105)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:60)
    at C.testOuter(C.java)
```

I replaced the actual parameter with EasyMock.IsA(String.class) but still no luck. I am pretty sure I am doing something fundamentally silly here.
Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think there are two issues here, one has to do with a missing call in your test code. The second has to do with your understanding of behavioral mocking and the difference between full and partial mocking.

## Missing Calls

You seem to be missing a call to [`PowerMock.mockStatic`](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) or one of the [`PowerMock.mockPartialMock`](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.2/apidocs/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.html#createPartialMock%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...%29) methods (see also [this](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPartial)). The first method will mock all static methods passed to it, while the second will mock only the list of methods it's given.

### An Example

Here's a complete example with two test methods that illustrate the two options. First, we have to annotate the test class using these two annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Dummy.class)
public class DummyTest {
```

The first annotation tells JUnit to run the test using PowerMockRunner. The second annotation tells PowerMock to prepare to mock the class Dummy.

#### Full Static Mock

Next, we'll look at the an example where all the static methods from class `Dummy` are mocked. What does this mean? It means essentially that we'll like to replace the actual implementation with fake ones (mocks). How should this fake implementation behave? This is what we specify in expectation.

Thus, in the `testStaticMock` method, we're telling EasyMock to give us a fake implementation of the two methods. We'll like the fake `Dummy.testOuter` to simply return `true`. And we'll like the fake Dummy.testInner to return `true` when passed the argument `"bb"`. Note that when these mocks are activated (`PowerMock.replayAll`), the test code will only run the fake methods and not the actual implementation -- this appears to be the source of your confusion. I have more to say on that later.

```
    @Test
    public void testStaticMock() {
        mockStatic(Dummy.class);
        EasyMock.expect(Dummy.testOuter()).andReturn(true);
        EasyMock.expect(Dummy.testInner("bb")).andReturn(true);
        replayAll();
        boolean status = Dummy.testOuter();
        Assert.assertTrue(status);
        status = Dummy.testInner("bb");
        Assert.assertTrue(status);
        verifyAll();
    }
```

#### Partial Static Mock

Here is another test where we don't mock all the methods, only the ones that we pass to `mockStaticPartial`. Below, we are telling PowerMock that we only want to mock the method `Dummy.testInner`. Thus, part of `Dummy` is mocked and the rest is the class under test.

```
    @Test
    public void testPartialStaticMock() {
        mockStaticPartial(Dummy.class, "testInner");
        EasyMock.expect(Dummy.testInner("someValue")).andReturn(true);
        replayAll();
        boolean status = Dummy.testOuter();
        verifyAll();
        Assert.assertTrue(status);
    }
}
```

And let the mocked class `Dummy` be defined as follows:

```
public class Dummy {
    public static boolean testInner(String s) {
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean testOuter() {
        String x = "someValue";
        return testInner(x);
    }
}
```

## Full mocking vs Partial Mocking

One thing to understand about full static mocking is that all the static methods are mocked. Thus, the method `testOuter` will be replace by a mocked version will have a implementation such as the following:

```
    public static boolean testOuter() {
        return true; //or whatever value is provided in the expectation
    }
```

Thus, we shouldn't expect the mocked version to invoke methods that the actual implementation does. We didn't want to care about the internals of the method. This was the reason, we decided to mock it anyway -- to replace its internals with a toy implementation, defined only by the expectation we set for it.

One the other hand, when we did partial mocking, we didn't mock `testOuter`, so we were invoking its actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations.It was my inability to distinguish partial vs. full mocking that led to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're only telling EasyMock to expect a call to testInner(), not testOuter().

```
 Unexpected method call testOuter():
```

Tried this:

```
EasyMock.expect(C.testInner("blabla")).andReturn(true);
EasyMock.expect(C.testOuter());
PowerMock.replayAll();
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I added the testOuter() expect but now I am getting: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call testOuter()
 at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.replay(MocksControl.java:174)

Comment: Hmm, apparently too long since I used EasyMock :)  Perhaps it was like this....EasyMock.expect(C.testOuter()).andReturn(true);

Answer (score 0):

Responding to provide an example call flow to mock a static void function using mockStaticPartial().

```
PowerMock.mockStaticPartial(Sample.class, "test");
Sample.test();
EasyMock.expectLastCall();
PowerMock.replay(Sample.class);
```

Later on in the test if you call something like:

```
assertFalse(Sample.returnFalseBool());
```

The test will call the real method since only the test() function has been mocked in this case.

**Disclaimer**: I am aware this might not be the BEST place to add this answer, but piecing together a few other answers to various related questions helped me come up with this answer, felt it necessary to put it somewhere.